# Getting Import error for module from a .pth file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, filepath, importerror

My team is using a custom built python library. There is a .pth file containing the path to that module file which I have placed into my python `site-packages` directory. However, whenever I try to execute any scripts that are using the said library I get a `Module not found error`. I am not very experienced with importing custom modules or how the python import process works. I am using a windows 10 machine, and python 2.7

Comment: Is the path in the `.pth` file valid on your system? Is the module being imported there?

Comment: You should probably include some information about the relevant parts of your directory structure and the contents of the `.pth` file.

Comment: The actual module is located on the network drive in a seperate directory. And I would assume that the .pth file contains the path to that directory on the network drive